# How to get Scenario name from cucumber js?

Tags: node.js, cucumberjs

In case of error I want to be able to log the scenario name.  I'm using cucumber.js and node.

> **Feature file**
>
> Scenario: As me I can go to google
>
> Given that I have a computer
>
> When I go to google
>
> Then I see wondrous stuff

I have tried the code below, but the name comes back as an empty string.

```
When(/^I go to google$/, (scenario) => {
// do something
var scenarioName = scenario.name;
});
```

By stepping through the code I can see that it's a function.
It has :

[[FunctionLocation]] = Object

[[Scopes]] = Scopes(6)

length = 2

name= ""

Comment: For debugging: add console.log(util.inspect(scenario)) and see what scenario object contains.

Comment: By stepping through I can see that it's a function. If I do your console.log line it outputs [Function] but that's it. I've put the properties of the function that I see when stepping through the code in the original question.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you can't do this in a Given or When, it has to be done in the Before or After hook:

```
Before((scenario) => {
const scenarioName = scenario.name;
console.log(`${scenarioName}`);
});
```

Comment: Once you get the name in Before hook, store them in the World object so that it can be retrieved in Given or When function statement.

Comment: Looks like there is no longer a name attribute - it is now in scenario.pickle.name (and if you want to use it to create a filename you'll want to do something like `.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '-')`

Comment: As other responses suggested, the name is within `scenario.pickle.name`

Answer (score 4):

I could get the scenario name using this code:

```
Before((scenario: any) => {
    console.log(`Starting scenario ${scenario.sourceLocation.uri}:${scenario.sourceLocation.line} (${scenario.pickle.name})`);
});
```

As you can see, there's more in there than just the scenario name. The entire test, with all the steps, tags, etc is in the object. I'm using CucumberJS 5.0.3.

Answer (score 2):

I found the scenario name using below code

```
console.log(`The scenario is ${JSON.stringify(scenario.pickle.name)}.`);
```